# How to display a Google Drive image using Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api

If I use the following, from Google's tutorial pages, to load an image, it works fine:

> // The very first Google Doodle!
>     app.add(app.createImage("http://www.google.com/logos/googleburn.jpg"));

but if I try to obtain a URL from own Google Docs, the image fails to load:

```
var image;
var url;    
var files = DocsList.getAllFiles();        
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {  
    url = files[i].getUrl();  
    app.add(app.createImage(image));  
    app.add(app.createLabel(url));  
}
```

The URL returned is not directly to the image but a Google Docs container of some sort:

> http://docs.google.com/a/--------.com/open?id=0B5B_X4WaXYC7cExRT3Nvb0hTamc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can not use images stored in Google Docs. Imgae URL should be a hotlink(Direct link) to that image.

```
app.createImage('YOUR_IMAGE_HOT_LINK_URL');
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems an extraordinary limitation of Google Apps if we can't access resources within the same eco-system - meaning we have to keep them in outside the sandbox.

Comment: Things are changing - within 24 hours of posting the question, Google Docs has added Google Drive to the Insert Image dialog of Google Document and Google Drawing. So it appears Google Drive is being closer integrated with Google Docs, and the next step presumably is for Google Apps Scripts to do similar, solving the original question.

Answer (score 6):

I know there's an accepted answer here but Since the deprecation of UiApp it's not really accurate anymore.  The following is script to read a given Google drive directory and pass every **publicly available** image to the template via an assets object with the modern App Script APIs.

```
function getAssets(driveDir) {
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(driveDir);
    var folder = (folders.hasNext())? folders.next() : false ;
    var assets = {};
    if(folder){
        var files = folder.getFiles();
        while (files.hasNext()) {
            var file = files.next();
            var fileName = file.getName();
            assets[fileName] = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=' + file.getId();
        }
    }
    return assets;
}
```

The doGet() function should include the assets

```
function doGet(e) {
    var form = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('form.html');
    form.assets = getAssets('Your-drive-folder-name');

    return form.evaluate();

}
```

And finally in the HTML template you will have access to your assets via the following code:

```
 <img src="<?= assets.fileName ?>" />
```

Again keep in mind that the assets have to be publicly available for image to be allowed on your google site/app script/whatever. You could set that via the getAssets() with the File.setSharing API method but I found that  setting the permissions on upload was not much of a hassel.

Comment: This works as of November 2019. I was able to put a GIF file in Google Drive, share it out, get the viewing URL using the code presented above and embed it in a local HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying an image in a UiApp from an authenticated URL is not possible, even from Google services like Sites, Docs, etc.  [Issue #912](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=912) documents this.

Answer (score -1):

You can store the image as an attachment to a Google Sites page and then access it using the Sites API of Google Apps Script.

Comment: Thanks, but that would not help colleagues (engineers) who are simply dropping images into Google Drive, and the Site needs to be able to pick them up. That's the reason for needing to access them from Google Drive programmatically.

Comment: How about having another script to move/copy images from Google Drive to a Google Sites page. You could filter by a label and have all images in a certain label automatically put up as attachments to a Sites page

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can do this but I fear it is not very reliable.  When you click the download button in the viewing container, that link will work.  However, you have to have the image publicly available.  Or share it to all users who will be able to view the Sheet or Doc.