# Referencing Project Files with Html Service

Tags: html, google-apps-script, project, image

**My Question:** Can I upload files to my Google Apps script project and reference those in an html file?

For example, let's say I have a project that looks like this:

---

myCode.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('myPage');
}
```

myPage.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    Hello World! Look at my picture of a cat! <img src="cat.jpg" />
  </body>
</html>
```

cat.jpg (an image of a cat in my project)

---

How can I make sure that `<img src="cat.jpg" />` references the `cat.jpg` that I have in my project? Can I even upload pictures to the project? I know that I could reference the image on another server, but I want this project to be contained. Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: No you cannot upload pictures to a Google Apps Script Project. But you can refer to images elsewhere like Gdrive or Picasa or even as a Attachement on a google site.

Comment: @Jacobvdb how do I reference a file on GDrive?

Comment: Take a look here in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097350/how-to-display-a-google-drive-image-using-google-apps-scripts). I did answer a bid to fast on this one, as it seems you can't use the `createImage()`. But you can use the `insertImage()` method.

Comment: I made a [example](https://sites.google.com/a/lagaroo.com.br/dev-test/dev-test/dev-test-drive-image) of the `insertImage()` though the `createImage()` does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a public folder in GDrive and get the ID of the folder and build a URL like below using the folder ID. This will be the path to that folder

```
var url = 'https://googledrive.com/host/'+'MY_PUBLIC_FOLDER_ID'
```

e.g `https://googledrive.com/host/0B2MdbzABFW_ubl9pY2FqS0FMMDQ`

Once you have built the URL, you can reference all your data inside that URL by using absolute path

e.g `pathToAnImage = url+'myImage.jpg'`

You may look on this post for more details.

- http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.in/2012/11/announcing-google-drive-site-publishing.html

Comment: For the record, the restriction that images must be public has been lifted.